# Can iPhone viruses damage internal data such as photos?

Tags: virus

After I clicked on a link on my iPhone safari app, an ad popped up from “Luckyguys.top” saying I won 1000 dollars. This is clearly a virus. What are the chances that is will damage the photos on my iPhone?

Comment: That’s not a virus, it’s a pop up ad which is very common. What makes you think this particular pop up “damages” photos?

Answer (score 1):

> After I clicked on a link on my iPhone safari app, an ad popped up...
>   This is clearly a virus.

No. This is a [pop up ad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pop-up_ad).  There is no evidence that it’s a [virus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_virus).

> What are the chances that is will damage the photos on my iPhone?

Zero. Did you give permissions to Safari to access your Photos library?  (Is rhetorical because the answer is “no”). Safari (and every app on iOS) is [sandboxed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandbox_(computer_security)) such that it cannot access other apps or data without your express consent. Since Safari doesn’t access photos, no website can do anything to them.